Cubic Surface of Unirational degree 2
I am studying unirationality of cubic surfaces. $V$ is called unirational, if there is such $n$, that exist dominant rational map $\varphi: P^n\rightarrow V$. Degree of that rational map is called unirational degree of V. I know examples of cubic surfaces with unirational degree 1, means that they are rational (e.g. Ferma surfaces). I know that they are sufaces with unirational degree 2, but i can't find examples. $\operatorname{char}(k)=0$. And are there any surfaces with unirational degree more than 2?
UPD. Question is motivated by remark 3.3 from that lecture. It states, that rational map of degree 2 always exists.

You made a typo with $\text{char}(k)=0$

Do you mean cubic surface or hypersurface?

@Mohan, original question was about surfaces, but if there are examples of hyperfaces, they will help me too
